# express-session is not saving cookies

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

I am using React with Nodejs and Express in making a login app. I want to only access my profile page when I am logged in. I use passport to authenticate and save cookies in my browser.

If I am not logged in, it should take me back to the home page, when I am logged in I should be able to access my profile.

Now when I also create an account, it should save a cookie in my browser so I can access my profile page, however, when I check my browser, there is no cookie for localhost.

There is something wrong with my code and I can't seem to figure it out. Can anyone help me here?

**This is my server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(
session({
secret: "This is our little secret",
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false,
})
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//connect to mongodb atlas
mongoose.connect(
"mongodb+srv://admin-darwin:test123@cluster0.nmhlm.mongodb.net/secretsDB",
{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
);

//user schema
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
username: String,
email: String,
password: String,
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

//user model
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.get("/profile", (req, res) => {
if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
console.log("yes");
} else {
res.send("not authenticated");
}
});

// create user
app.post("/new", (req, res) => {
User.register(
{ username: req.body.username },
req.body.password,
(err, user) => {
if (err) {
console.log(err);
res.redirect("/new");
} else {
passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, () => {
res.send("ok");
});
}
}
);
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
console.log("server running on port 5000");
});
```

Comment: Remember to produce a [MINIMAL reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: First of all, I would suggest you to refactor a bit. This increases readability, would also significantly improve the probability of catching minor bugs. Keep passport-setup, db-setup, etc in separate files.